# Does c++ time difference function calculate daylight savings?

Tags: c++, time.h

If I use the C++ time difference (timediff) function to caculate a the difference between 2 times and the later time is after the time change for day light savings will the returned difference caculate this.

E.g. I have a time of 23:00 and a time of 11:00. The time changes in the middle of this time i.e it goes forward one hour.

Will I get 12 hours or 11 difference?

Comment: I cant find any function called timediff, can you show code? If you mean Cs difftime, then both parameters are time_t (seconds since epoch) so it does not make sense to talk about any timezone/dst there

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/difftime/ It seems the question boils down to a data question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is `difftime`, not `timediff`.  And it takes two
`time_t` as arguments; `time_t` typically represent UTC, not
a particular local time, so the summer time issue doesn't occur.

Comment: It doesn't "typcially represent UTC", it does typically represent seconds since epoch, that is an amount of seconds passed since a specific point in time. Timezones only get involved there if you try to convert that seconds into a representation that has days, hours etc. in it.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Since the epoch is specified in UTC, the time it represents it UTC.  You're quite right in a formal sense, but I was speaking in a much more general way: we use `time_t` as a representation of time (last modified time of a file, for example), and when it represents a time (because we can also use it to represent and interval), that time is UTC.  The fact that the representation is actually the interval from a specific point in time is, more or less, an implementation detail.  (In the case where we use it as a time, of course.)

Comment: I found that exactly that thinking of it as an implementation detail is confusing the hell out of people. They start doing things like wanting to convert a time_t from UTC to their timezone, or similar. While it is correct that the formal specification references UTC (maybe 00:00 1.1.1970 is easier to remember), there is no difference in the value of SSE when you specify the epoch in a timezone. As such I usually insist on SSE being "timezone less" and found that this is much easier for people to understand, simply because SSE has a true meaning even without any timezone.

Comment: To be pedantic, `time_t` is not a time point, but rather a duration elapsed since a well known time point (epoch). `epoch + time_t` yields a time point. Nevertheless, standard C time functions assume a hardcoded epoch.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: What _really_ confused the hell of of me is why there is a library function for such a trivial thing as `return (a - b) >= 0 ? (a-b) : -(a-b);` (or something similar). Most of the time you know that `a >= b` anyway, so you can just write `a-b`. The presence of a library function indeed _suggests_ (wrongly) that it does some kind of complicated time zone / dst calculations rather than a simple subtraction.

Comment: @Damon: This is because POSIX allows time_t to be something else than an integer.

Comment: Well, `a-b` works the same for `int` or `long long` or `double` (or whatever one might choose), which are pretty much the only allowable types ("_time_t and clock_t shall be integer or real-floating types_").

Comment: @Damon: difftime is a very old function that was used on systems that predate POSIX. The Linux datetime man page remarks that it could be implemented as a simple subtraction, and then says, "On other systems, the data type time_t might use some other encoding where subtraction doesn't work directly."

Comment: For that matter, I seem to recall that some early Mac OS compilers didn't use the Unix epoch (Jan. 1, 1970), but rather the Mac epoch (Jan. 1, 1984).

Comment: @BobMurphy And Excel uses 1 Jan. 1900.  The one standardized (outside of programming langauges) would be 12:00:00 1 Jan -4713 (the base for Julian days).  But of course, if you're counting seconds, and your largest type is 32 bits, this creates some problems.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you will.  I had to deal with it back in visual studio 6 back in the Y2k days.  Then they changed the DST rules invalidating the code.

If you see a mysterious jump of an hour forward, and an hour back it is DST rearing its ugly head in the RTL.